# Como obter valores vizinhos à determinado offset de um array?

Tags: php, array, lógica, matemática, offset

Estou tendo dificuldades em extrair uma parcela de um array indexado sequencial qualquer, como um simples [range()](http://www.php.net/range).

O problema é que preciso especificar um offset de partida e um limite maior ou igual a 1. Esse limite controlaria quantos elementos seriam buscados antes e depois de dado offset, além dele mesmo, claro. Por exemplo:

```
$letras = range( 'A', 'Z' );
$offset = 3;
$limite = 2;
```

Nesse caso a rotina deveria retornar o quarto offset (D), dois à frente (E e F) e dois atrás (B e C).

Já se esses valores mudassem para, quem sabe:

```
$offset = 10;
$limite = 3;
```

A mesma rotina deveria retornar o décimo primeiro índice (K), três à frente (L, M e N) e três atrás (H, I e J).

Pois bem, inicialmente eu recorri ao [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/array_slice) acreditando ser a ferramenta correta para o trabalho. No entanto usá-la se provou mais difícil do que pareceu pois o terceiro argumento da função trabalha com comprimentos e não com offsets:

```
$collection = range( 'A', 'Z' );
$offset     = 10;
$limit      = 3;

$length = count( $collection );

if( $offset >= $length ) {
    throw new \OutOfRangeException( 'Requested offset exceeds the size of Collection' );
}

$start = ( $offset - $limit ) >= 0 ? ( $offset - $limit ) : 0;
$end   = $limit + 2;

$slice = array_slice( $collection, $start, $end );
```

Imagino eu que o que esteja procurando seja uma solução matemática mas não estou sabendo como montar a lógica.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Uma informação adicional muito importante é que a solução, seja ela qual for, também não se apóie naquelas "feitiçarias" que vemos, por exemplo, invertendo o as chaves array com seus valores. Isso porque aqui, neste exemplo, estou demonstrando com um array simples preenchido com letras mas o uso real será uma Coleção de Objetos, por exemplo:

```
$std1 = new\stdClass;
$std1 -> name = 'Name #1';

$std2 = new\stdClass;
$std2 -> name = 'Name #2';

$std3 = new\stdClass;
$std3 -> name = 'Name #3';

$std4 = new\stdClass;
$std4 -> name = 'Name #4';

$std5 = new\stdClass;
$std5 -> name = 'Name #5';

$collection = [ $std1, $std2, $std3, $std4, $std5 ];
```

Mas, lógico e evidente que não meros Objetos stdClass, tampouco Objetos que já tenham alguma interface implementada, apesar de todos meus Objetos estenderem da mesma classe-base por outros motivos alheios à este tópico.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o próprio `array_slice` que mencionou ou poderia usar um simples `for`, acho que este último seria mais fácil, também poderia usar `next` e `prev`, enfim tem várias opções.

```
function selecionar($array, $comeco, $limite){

    $comeco  -= $limite + 1;
    $limite   = $limite * 2 + 1;

    for($limite; $limite > 0; $limite--){

        if(isset($array[$comeco + $limite])){
            $selecao[] = $array[$comeco + $limite];
        }

    }

    return $selecao;

}
```

Logo, usando:

```
echo implode(',', selecionar($collection, 3, 2));
```

Irá retornar exatamente `F,E,D,C,B`.

---

Usando o `array_slice` sem qualquer correção (se o limit for maior que o offset terá problemas, por exemplo), poderia usar:

```
array_slice($collection, $offset - $limit, $limit * 2 + 1);
```

Logo:

```
$collection = range( 'A', 'Z' );
$offset = 3;
$limit = 2;

echo implode(',',  array_slice($collection, $offset - $limit, $limit * 2 + 1));
```

Resultaria exatamente em `B,C,D,E,F`.

Comment: Sua solução iterando funcionou, m ordem reversa, claro, mas funcionou. Mas eu realmente queria tentar de todo o possível para evitar um loop. Já a segunda, que por sinal eu havia imaginado e tentando mas omiti do post original, não funcionou para offsets muito pequenos. Ex: `$offset = 0` e `$limite = 2` faz com que `$offset - $limit` dê negativo e array_slice() pega a partir do final.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que se você fizer `$offset - start + $limit + 1` deve ter o comportamento esperado. Por exemplo:

```
$offset = 10;
$limite = 3;
```

Nesse caso `$start = 7`, já que $start = $offset - $limit = 7 e $end = 10  - 7 + $limit + 1 = 7. Então  o terceiro parametro da função array_slice terá tamanho 7, indo do indice 7 ao indice 13 (8 letra até a 14 letra do alfabeto).

```
<?php
$collection = range( 'A', 'Z' );
$offset     = 20;
$limit      = 2;

$length = count( $collection );

if( $offset >= $length ) {
    throw new \OutOfRangeException( 'Requested offset exceeds the size of Collection' );
}

$start = ( $offset - $limit ) >= 0 ? ( $offset - $limit ) : 0;
$end   = $offset - $start + $limit + 1;

$slice = array_slice( $collection, $start, $end );

var_dump($slice);
```

Comment: Embora um teste automatizado fosse melhor, pelo que eu puder testar manualmente a sua solução para o `$end` matou o problema. Porém, antes de marcar como resolvido, lendo o manual sobre array_slice() vi que se o terceiro parâmetro `length` for negativo ela vai continuar incluindo a partir do final do array. Alguma chance de a sua lógica dar negativo?